# Playing wav with HTML5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, wav, text-to-speech

I am trying to output a text-to-speech wav file and play it with the HTML5 `<audio>` tag. The text-to-speech method is outputting the bytes, but the html5 control isn't playing it.

If instead of streaming the bytes directly to the control, i save it as a file first, then convert the file to bytes with filestream and output them, it starts to play, but i don't want to have to save the file every time. I'm using MVC 4.

```
    // in a class library
    public byte[] GenerateAudio(string randomText)
    {
        MemoryStream wavAudioStream = new MemoryStream();
        SpeechSynthesizer speechEngine = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        speechEngine.SetOutputToWaveStream(wavAudioStream);
        speechEngine.Speak(randomText);
        wavAudioStream.Flush();
        Byte[] wavBytes = wavAudioStream.GetBuffer();
        return wavBytes;
    }

    // in my controller
    public ActionResult Listen()
    {
        return new FileContentResult(c.GenerateAudio(Session["RandomText"].ToString()), "audio/wav");
    }

   // in my view
   <audio controls autoplay>
       <source src="@Url.Content("~/Captcha/Listen")" type="audio/wav" />
            Your browser does not support the <audio> element.
   </audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also playing back a wav file to an audio element, and your code has the same logic as mine. I just noticed that you are flushing your stream before you return the byte array, which will seem to be empty.

Also, you can use file as return type and pass the byte array to its constructor. The content type is just the same as in your code. I would like to mention (maybe it could be a help also) that I used 2 streams: an outside scope stream and the actual stream where the data will be saved. After I have populated the actual stream I copied its contents to the outside stream using `stream.CopyTo()` and the instance of that outside stream is the one I used in my return statement. This avoids the error "Cannot Access Closed stream" (not the exact the error statement).